# Create c++ Library in Eclipse for using in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: eclipse, visual-c++, user-interface, visual-studio-2012

I coded a c++ Library in Eclipse. Now I wanna add a GUI, which I want to make with Visual studio. Although I'm using the VS Compiler in Eclipse I cannot transfer the code from Eclipse 1:1 to Visual Studio.

Is there a way to create a DLL or sth. else in Eclipse which I can import in Visual Studio?

Thanks 
Florian

Comment: Why cannot you transfer the code 1:1?

Comment: I'm using an external Library(ICU) which I don't get to run in Visual Studio

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can use ICU with Visual Studio.